# Slurm: "Connection refused" for certain sacctmgr commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, slurm

I have an existing slurm cluster up and running but as of today without a configuration change I get an error when I run certain `sacctmgr` commands and `slurmdbd` crashes:

```
$ sacctmgr list associations
sacctmgr: error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent connection to slurm.domain.com:6819: Connection refused
sacctmgr: error: slurmdbd: Getting response to message type 1410
sacctmgr: error: slurmdbd: DBD_GET_ASSOCS failure: Connection refused
 Error with request: Connection refused
```

The `systemctl status` shows:

```
Jul 03 10:01:46 slurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jul 03 10:01:46 slurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

and the slurmdbd.log says:

```
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.816] debug2: Opened connection 9 from 127.0.0.1
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.817] debug:  REQUEST_PERSIST_INIT: CLUSTER:slurmcluster VERSION:8192 UID:0 IP:127.0.0.1 CONN:9
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.817] debug2: acct_storage_p_get_connection: request new connection 1
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.861] debug2: DBD_FINI: CLOSE:0 COMMIT:0
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.862] debug4: got 0 commits
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.949] debug2: DBD_GET_ASSOCS: called
[2020-07-03T10:01:45.950] debug4: 9(as_mysql_assoc.c:2032) query
call get_parent_limits('assoc_table', 'root', 'slurmcluster', 0); select @par_id, @mj, @msj, @mwpj, @mtpj, @mtpn, @mtmpj, @mtrm, @def_qos_id, @qos, @delta_qos;
```

However other commands work (restart of slurmdbd needed after crash):

```
$ sacctmgr show cluster
   Cluster     ControlHost  ControlPort   RPC     Share GrpJobs       GrpTRES GrpSubmit MaxJobs       MaxTRES MaxSubmit     MaxWall                  QOS   Def QOS
---------- --------------- ------------ ----- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ----------- -------------------- ---------
slurmclus+       127.0.0.1         6817  8192         1                                                                                           normal
```

I can connect to the database and execute commands. Also, I can connect via `telnet slurm.domain.com 6819`.

I'm using slurm 17.11.2 with MySQL 5.7 from the standard Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Comment: Are you using MariaDB or MySQL? Which version? slurmdbd was killed with 11/SEGV which is Segmentation Fault. If you are with MariaDB perhaps it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão: I'm using MySQL also from the standard Ubuntu repositories. I don't know about hardware issues. It's a virtual machine that works fine otherwise and it's odd that this only happens on some commands.

Comment: Which version? It’s higher than 5.5? If yes change to MariaDB. I’m almost sure that will fix your issue. If yes I will write a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, it's MySQL 5.7.

Comment: If you’re up to, change to MariaDB. I’ve got a lot of issues with DBD and MySQL after the fork on SLURM. Going to bed right now, so please let me know if you tried the change when I woke up.

Comment: I don't really know what I need to take care of when switching from MySQL to MariaDB. So please post an answer.

Comment: If you don't care about previous data you can just remove and install MariaDB instead. Many times it will even use the tables from MySQL since MariaDB is supposed to be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: I want to keep the data. When installing MariaDB it says that the existing MySQL data is not compatible. I tried to restore a dump but it didn't take over slurms accounting settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was an unattended upgrade. Therein MySQL was updated from `5.7.29` to `5.7.30`. Everything works with MySQL `5.7.29`. The [changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-30.html) doesn't include something obvious, but according to the [slurm-users mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slurm-users/rcWx3oL67tQ) this is the problem:

> Seems that (at least for the mysql procedure get_parent_limits) mySQL
> 5.7.30 returns NULL where mySQL 5.7.29 returned an empty string.